# Is it possible to display NodeJS app path inside top command's output?

Tags: ubuntu, ps, top

I'm trying to monitor system processes cpu & memory usage on a Ubuntu server with many running NodeJS applications.

`top` command only shows "node" without specifying which script is it.

```
1520 root      20   0  716316  84036  20496 S   1.7   8.4   3:20.12 node
```

Therefore I have to execute `ps -aef | grep node` to see which exact app it is:

```
root        1520    1435  2 06:15 ?        00:03:20 /usr/bin/node /test.js
```

Is it possible to combine outputs so I can see `/test.js` inside `top` output?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found it:

```
top -c
```

Or can press `c` after opening top.